# Using csv files as inputs to python script from command line (without importing libraries)

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments

I am solving a problem where I am trying to run a python (3.10) script which uses data from 3 different csv files. In the final product I want to be able to run it directly from the command line, and generate 2 output csv files. The command should look as follows:

```
python code.py -t input1.csv -p input2.csv -s input3.csv 
--team-report=output1.csv --product-report=output2.csv
```

Is there a way to do it without importing any libraries? The methods I have tried used the `sys` and `argparse` libraries, however, I'm not allowed to use anything other than built-in packages.

Comment: `sys` and `argparse` are "built-in packages" (they are in the standard library).

Comment: The question says: Code should only use built-in Python packages (and not use third-party packages such as pandas) 

so it will be fine to use argparse?

Comment: Is there any way to do it without importing anything? As it would be more impressive.

Comment: Yes, they are not third-party, but are part of any standard Python installation.

Comment: Yes, you can reimplement everything yourself (I'm not sure about `sys`).